# Does a bash subshell spawn a new `bash` process?

Tags: bash, subshell

I am reading [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/). In the "Jobs and sessions" section there is an example of a user using an xterm:

```
$ cat
hello
hello
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
$ ls | sort
```

And there is a table listing the processes involved: `xterm`, `bash` (child of the `xterm`), and the three last processes (`cat`, `ls` and `sort`) all have the same PPID (parent process ID) -- they are all children of the same `bash` process.

Now, I know that pipelines in bash are executed in *subshells*. I have always thought that this subshell thing meant that there was an extra `bash` process for each subshell. My question is: shouldn't there be another two `bash` processes, both children of the first `bash`, and then `ls` would be a child of the first `bash`, and `sort` would be a child of the second `bash`? Is the table in the article simplified, or is my understanding of subshells wrong?

Comment: The behaviour of Bash is configurable; your sweeping generalities are not entirely accurate with the default settings (notably 'pipelines…are executed in subshells' is not accurate). See [`PIPESTATUS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) and [`shopt -s lastpipe`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) and [`set -o pipefail`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programs are executed in child processes, but these are not subshells. The shell forks a child, redirects standard input/output/error as necessary, and then immediately calls `execv()` to execute the program.

For a very brief period the child process is still running `bash`, but we don't consider this a subshell  because it's not doing any shell command processing -- that was all done in the original shell, and the child is just starting up the external program (as if via an explicit `exec` for commands like `ls`).

In the case of a pipeline, if any of the commands are shell built-ins, they run in a subshell. So if you do:

```
ls | read var
```

it will create two child processes. One child will run `ls`, the other will be a subshell executing `read var`.

Comment: In my understanding, what you described is true for processes like the `cat` command above. But my question is specifically about pipelines. Pipelines always run in a subshell, right?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain subshells running in a pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

Invoking an executable, whether directly or via a pipe, does not spawn a subshell. Only explicitly invoking it within a subshell (via `(...)`, `$(...)`, and so on) does so.

Comment: I thought that every pipeline forced subshells to spawn. Is it wrong?

Comment: A pipe only forces a subshell to spawn if what follows the pipe is a shell construct, e.g. `while` or a function.